CPU clock rate on Apple Silicon detected by Geekbench
I am trying to figure out which MacBook I want to buy. One thing I did is to look at Geekbench. I found the following two results or probably two MacBooks:
https://browser.geekbench.com/v6/cpu/compare/5703989?baseline=5703318
I am not sure, but the all M2 chips should have the same CPU clock rate, shouldn't they? How come these two MacBooks show a different clock rate?
